# Trouble converting Android Studio project new API key

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I made a project which uses the Google Maps SDK for Android back in 2018, which is basically a geolocator. I am now trying to restart the project, however Google has changed how to implement your API key into your program. Does anyone know the conventional method for adding your API key to an Android Studio project in 2019. Version 3.3.

The project originated on my desktop, where I had not updated android studio in a while. I took the project and loaded it onto my laptop that was running Android Studio 3.3. It built perfectly and works functionally perfectly except the map would only show the google watermark.

Where do I actually put my key now? I've read that it's supposed to be in gradle.properties, but also in other places. So what are the conventional methods for getting this to work?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tommy.app">

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapSearch"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_map_search">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.tommy.app.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Map2"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_map2"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Map should geolocate the location entered in the first activity.

Answer (score -1):

If you are having trouble porting your project machine to machine, just go to the API key credentials through Google Cloud Development, find the key you originally used, add a new restriction for the same project name, but with your new SHA1 (from the new PC). Look up keystore to find out your SHA.